# Lubuntu Firefox is always running

Tags: lubuntu, firefox, autostart

I have a very persistent Firefox. Even after a reboot the process is running, and starts by itself again if I kill it. Yesterday, I heard the audio of the last YouTube video after a reboot.

I tried to:

- Delete the `.mozilla` folder.
- Search for autostart files and erase any reference to FF:

  ```
  /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu-Netbook/autostart
  /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart
  /usr/lib/openbox/openbox-autostart
  /usr/lib/openbox/openbox-xdg-autostart
  ```
- This is the output of the command `cd / && locate autostart > ~/list.txt`

  ```
  /etc/xdg/autostart
  /etc/xdg/autostart/blueman.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gdu-notification-daemon.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-gpg.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-secrets.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gnome-keyring-ssh.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/gsettings-data-convert.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/jockey-gtk.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/nm-applet.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/notification-daemon.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/print-applet.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio-kde.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/pulseaudio.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/update-notifier.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-power-manager.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-settings-helper-autostart.desktop
  /etc/xdg/autostart/xfce4-volumed.desktop
  /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu/autostart
  /etc/xdg/lxsession/Lubuntu-Netbook/autostart
  /etc/xdg/openbox/autostart
  /home/USER/.config/autostart
  /home/USER/.config/autostart/blueman.desktop
  /home/USER/.config/autostart/jockey-gtk.desktop
  /home/USER/.config/autostart/lxrandr-autostart.desktop
  /home/USER/.config/autostart/xfce4-settings-helper-autostart.desktop
  /usr/lib/openbox/openbox-autostart
  /usr/lib/openbox/openbox-xdg-autostart
  /usr/share/autostart
  /usr/share/autostart/konqy_preload.desktop
  /usr/share/autostart/nepomukcontroller.desktop
  /usr/share/autostart/nepomukserver.desktop
  /usr/share/gdm/autostart
  /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow
  /usr/share/gdm/autostart/LoginWindow/lxsession.desktop
  /usr/share/icons/hicolor/48x48/apps/xfce4-autostart-editor.png
  ```

What can I do? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is there a file in `/home/USER/.config/autostart`?

Comment: I explored the list I have wrote right now (except the .desktop files) and found no reference to the program.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long to fit in a comment so I'll have to phrase this as an answer. Sorry for the delay in answering but I'm going through old questions to see if there's any hope at finding a resolution.

Crack open your terminal and enter this command:

`sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=true/NoDisplay=False/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`

Enter your password and press enter (note that when you enter your password there are no asterisks or anything).

Now, open your start menu and preferences and then click on Default Applications for LXSession. In there you will see, on the left, Autostart.

Any hidden services and programs should now be visible. Is Firefox in there and hidden? If so then untick the box.

Now, let's put it back because it may complain about updating the database next time. To do that we basically just swap the command around like so:

`sudo sed -i 's/NoDisplay=False/NoDisplay=True/g' /etc/xdg/autostart/*.desktop`

Of course you can also just look in `/etc/xdg/autostart` and see if something is amiss but where's the fun in that?

Anyhow, if this doesn't answer your question and you've since resolved the question then please let us know what you did to resolve it so that others may learn from your experience.